# Find an unknown length using sohcahtoa (Trigonometry)

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, mathematics

Here is a calculator for an unknown side in a right-angle. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
import math
def trigonometry(angle, side_length, known, unknown):
    o, h, a = 'opposite', 'hypotenuse', 'adjacent'
    sohcahtoa = {o: {h: math.sin, a: math.tan},
                 h: {o: math.sin, a: math.cos},
                 a: {o: math.tan, h: math.cos}}
    function = sohcahtoa[known][unknown]
    return side_length / function(math.radians(angle)) if known == 'opposite' or (known == a and unknown == h)\
        else function(math.radians(angle) * side_length)

    print(trigonometry(30, 1, 'opposite', 'hypotenuse'))
```

I particularly dislike this line as it is basically brute force and very long.

```
return side_length / function(math.radians(angle)) if known == 'opposite' or (known == a and unknown == h)\
        else function(math.radians(angle) * side_length)
```

**Test Calls**

Here are two test calls to make sure the code works.

**Call:** trigonometry(30, 1, 'opposite', 'hypotenuse')
**Expected Output:** 2

**Call:** trigonometry(30, 2, 'hypotenuse', 'opposite')
**Expected Output:** 1

Answer (score 4):

- You know the equations, but fail to return them in your `sohcahtoa` dictionary.
  Take 'soh':

  \$\sin(\theta) = \frac{o}{a}\$
  \$o = a\sin(\theta)\$
  \$a = \frac{o}{\sin(\theta)}\$

  From this you know all the equations, and you know they follow the form `op(side, trig_fn(angle))`. And so you should expand your `sohcahtoa` dictionary to contain this too.
- I'd recommend you make an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum) for opposite, adjacent and hypotenuse, so that you get an actual error, rather than hidden errors, if you mis-spell them. (Yes you should be careful of this.)
- It doesn't make sense to create `sohcahtoa` every time you call the function.

And so I'd change to:

```
from enum import Enum
import math
import operator

class TrigSides(Enum):
    OPPOSITE = 'opposite'
    ADJACENT = 'adjacent'
    HYPOTENUSE = 'hypotenuse'

SOHCAHTOA = {
    TrigSides.OPPOSITE: {
        TrigSides.HYPOTENUSE: (math.sin, operator.truediv),
        TrigSides.ADJACENT: (math.tan, operator.truediv)
    },
    TrigSides.HYPOTENUSE: {
        TrigSides.OPPOSITE: (math.sin, operator.mul),
        TrigSides.ADJACENT: (math.cos, operator.mul)
    },
    TrigSides.ADJACENT: {
        TrigSides.HYPOTENUSE: (math.cos, operator.truediv),
        TrigSides.OPPOSITE: (math.tan, operator.mul)
    }
}

def trigonometry(angle, side, known, unknown):
    trig_fn, op = SOHCAHTOA[known][unknown]
    return op(side, trig_fn(math.radians(angle)))
```